# How could i store keyboard input in Windows using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, keylogger

I've tried searching for pyHook documentation but failed to understand it...

I've also tried watching many tutorials on youtube but they won't explain how to do it, instead they just do it.

I've also searched on StackOverflow posts BUT they are mostly related to games, and store keystrokes made on the python interpreter instead of Windows.

Comment: where to store ? In variable ? In file ? In database ?

Comment: Variable or file would be fine. It's for a keylogger.

Comment: writing in file is universal problem which has nothing to do with PyHook. Do you know how to save any text in file ? if not then you have to learn it first.

Comment: Yes. I do know how to work with file objects.

Comment: I would like to know how to actually have access to the input.

Comment: in documentation you have example [Keyboard Hook](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from msvcrt import getch
key = getch()
```

or to capture them forever...

```
keys = []
while True:
    keys.append(getch())
```

**update**

try using keyboard.
https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: Thank's for the reply! It doesn't work tho... That only works if input is given through python's interpreter and i actually want to capture input from the computer's OS.

Comment: @MatiSandacz my bad, try keyboard instead.  Very simple to use.